# Firefox Extension Development - Data Storage - is Firefox Preferences a good place?

Tags: configuration, firefox-addon

I have developed a Firefox add-on that needs to save some user-data in the local machine. Right now, I use the filesystem functionality that Firefox provides to create some folders and files in the user's system.

Portability is a problem. I designed it for Windows XP. But, Vista's folder structure is different (inside the app data). Linux is completely different. I do an OS check and create/read/write files accordingly. Suddenly, I need to support Macs!

I thought why not save the data in the Firefox preferences. I will use the Preference Manager.

On an average, the total amount of data hardly goes beyond 100KB. But the thing is, in rare cases, the data could get quite big - a few megabytes in the worst case. So, is it a good idea to save it as preference values?

I know that is not what it is meant for, but it will save me a lot of headaches.

Even if it is a bad idea, just let me know about the performance or other issues (if any) of storing that much data in preferences.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

With newer versions of Firefox you can use [SQLite to store data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Storage). The [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) API in JavaScript isn't terribly good, but from Firefox 3.6 it's starting to get pretty solid (asynch fetching of data, binding multiple sets of data, etc).

You can open/create a file in the profile directory using the following code. It works on all platforms Firefox runs on:

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
                     .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties)
                     .get("ProfD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
file.append("my_db_file_name.sqlite");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to locate the profile or extensions directory of firefox via code. You can even locate the directory of your own extension. Portability shouldn't be a problem using this approach.

You can find instructions at the [MDC (File I/O)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO#Getting_your_extension%27s_folder).

I wouldn't advice saving data in the preferences. Anyway, instead of using bare file i/o you may look into sqlite-databases - ubiquity uses those as well.

Cheers.

Comment: Someone may google 'ubiquity' as Majid reportedly did. If you do so beware of the first search result which points to a URL at "rocket.ryerson...;. This site is very suspicious. It tries to fool you to download a copy of the add-on hosted on his own server, only, he has crafted it to look exactly like Mozilla's.  Thanks to Majid for this information.