# Sortable Divs That Save Locations

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, swap, html

I'm trying to make my first Firefox extension, that replaces the new tab page with a more Chrome-like tab page. one of the features is tiles of your "most visited sites," that you can drag-and-drop to reorder. I have them dragging and dropping, but I have no idea how to save the new locations of the DIVs.

This is the script I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery.fn.redswap = function(options){
    var selectedItems=this;
    redsettings = jQuery.extend({
         speed:"Medium",
         opacity:0.7
      }, options);
    $(selectedItems).mouseover(function(){
        $(selectedItems).disableSelection();
        $(selectedItems).droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                dropindex=$(selectedItems).index(this);
                var dragposition=$(selectedItems[dragindex]).position();
                var dropposition=$(selectedItems[dropindex]).position();

                withDifference=parseInt(dragposition.left)-parseInt(dropposition.left);
                heightDifference=parseInt(dragposition.top)-parseInt(dropposition.top);

                $(selectedItems[dropindex]).animate({
                    left:'+='+withDifference,
                    top:'+='+heightDifference
                },redsettings.speed,function(){

                });

                $(selectedItems[dragindex]).animate({
                    left:'+='+(withDifference*(-1)),
                    top:'+='+(heightDifference*(-1))
                },redsettings.speed,function(){
                    //Complete
                });


            },


        });

        $(this).draggable({ 
        opacity:redsettings.opacity, 
        helper: 'clone',
        containment: 'parent', 
        scroll: false,
        drag:function(event, ui){
                dragindex=$(selectedItems).index(this);
            }

        });

    });
    };

});

    // Settings

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#wrapper").tabs();
    $("div[id*='box']").redswap({
        speed:'slow',
        opacity:.75
    });
});
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<div id="1box" class="item">
    <a href="http://www.google.com/reader/view"><img src="thumbs/01.png" border="0" />
    <h1>Google Reader</a></h1><a href="#" class="x"></a><a href="#" class="tack"></a>
</div>
<div id="2box" class="item">
    <a href="https://mail.google.com/"><img src="thumbs/02.png" border="0" />
    <h1>Gmail</a></h1><a href="#" class="x"></a><a href="#" class="tack"></a>
</div>
<div id="3box" class="item">
    <a href="http://calendar.google.com/"><img src="thumbs/03.png" border="0" />
    <h1>Google Calendar</a></h1><a href="#" class="x"></a><a href="#" class="tack"></a>
</div>
<div id="4box" class="item">
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/"><img src="thumbs/04.png" border="0" />
    <h1>Twitter</a></h1><a href="#" class="x"></a><a href="#" class="tack"></a>
</div>
```

The HTML isn't final yet, but it does drag and drop. Any idea how I can save the new order of the DIVs, so that when I close out and open it up again, it's the new configuration? If it can't be done with this script, then I'm fine being pointed to a new version.

Keep in mind I'm very very new to JavaScript, so please treat me like I'm an idiot :)

Also, if you're interested in helping me on the coding part of things, send me a message.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for some sort of storage to contain your sequence information.

Three approaches that are applicable to Firefox extensions are discussed in this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361250/firefox-extension-development-data-storage-is-firefox-preferences-a-good-plac)

Either the SQLite or File System option would work well for your application, I think.