# handling firefox extension prefrences across sessions

Tags: firefox, session, firefox-addon

I'm working on a firefox extention. I like to give some options for the user, like setting background
color and others. I need to retrive these options for each tabs. Where should i can store the values?

how can i get around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the XPCOM interfaces to Firefox' preferences system:

```
var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"]
                      .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefService)
                      .getBranch("extensions.yourextension.");
prefs.setIntPref("yourPersistedValue", 42);
```

See [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Preferences) for more information and code samples.

Alternatively, you can use SQLite. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361250/firefox-extension-development-data-storage-is-firefox-preferences-a-good-plac/1895895#1895895) for details.

Comment: Whether it stores values in mozilla.org, if not then what's the purpose of it? Thanks.